# Array formulas and PasteSpecial:=Formats

Tags: excel, excel-2007, array-formulas, vba

I have this small issue in a workbook. I wanted to simply a very long function by using array formulas. The formula works well and produces the expected results. However, in my VBA macro I copy and then I do a formula paste and then a format paste. The format paste crashes with : "Impossible to paste because copy and paste zones are of different size" (or similar to that). This problem is solved if I use any other formula that is not an array formula.

Did anyone experience this before and find a proper solution ? I can't seem to find help an answer on Google. I'll post code if needed, but it is rather straight forward (`Row.Copy ... Rows(something, something).PasteSpecial...`) and works with a non-array formula anyway.

Edit: The code:

```
 sRapDetail = "rap - détails"

    Sheets(sRapDetail).Select
    iStart = 17
    iFormuleExceptionRNIAC = 13
    iFormule1 = 14
    iFormule2 = 15
    iFormuleExceptionAR = 16
    range(Rows(iStart - 1), Rows(1000)).Hidden = False

    iLastRow = Cells(65535, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    range("A" & iStart & ":AL" & iLastRow).Select
'    selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
'    selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    'RNIAC
    Sheets("Zoom0").Select

    If Cells(21, "B").Value = "" Or Cells(22, "B").Value = "" Then
        iLastRow = 21
    Else
        iLastRow = Cells(21, "B").End(xlDown).Row
    End If
     iNbRow = iLastRow - 20

    Sheets(sRapDetail).Select
    Rows(iFormuleExceptionRNIAC).Select
    selection.Copy
    range(Rows(iStart), Rows(iStart - 1 + iNbRow)).Select
    selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

(And yes I know the use of `selection` is ugly (or at least in this case) but this was written by a colleague)

Comment: Could you post your code? I just recorded a macro that copied an Array formula then paste-specialed the formulas then paste specialed the formats and it worked just fine...

Comment: ... I recorded a macro and it works just fine and your code (although weird in a few different ways) doesn't seem to show me any reason why it would break at the pastespecial line ... I don't know what to tell you....

Comment: Last thought: are you sure that the *exact same code* works when **ALL YOU REPLACE IS THE ARRAY FORMULA IN THE COPIED CELL - Nothing else**?? ... The only thing that makes sense would be if you're trying to paste formatting into merged cells or something like that

Comment: Yes. I changed the formula to `1 + 1` and then to the old formula which is something like `ABS(...) + ABS(...)...` and both cases worked. Replacing that formula with the array formula makes the macro crash. I am only changing one cell.

Comment: Oh and we do not use merged cells because they cause more problems than they solve so that could not be the case. I know for a fact there are no merged cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you cannot copy an array formula on top of itself.

For example, if you have an array formula in cell A1 and you want to copy it down to cell A10, you can't copy A1 and highlight A1:A10 and paste. It won't work. You have to copy A1, then highlight A2:A10.

That said, the problem most likely exists in the fact that the row from `Rows(iFormuleExceptionRNIAC)` probably intersects with this `range(Rows(iStart), Rows(iStart - 1 + iNbRow))`

If you can ensure they don't intersect, copying the array formulas will work.

Comment: I will definitely check that when I get the chance to. Thanks !

Comment: Noooo.. Unfortunately this is not the case. `iFormuleExceptionRNIAC` is 13 and `iStart` is 17 so the ranges do not overlap. My team leader thinks it might have something to do with my MSO Service Pack.

Comment: `iStart = 17`, but if `iStart - 1 + iNbRow` evaluates to anything less than 17, it is going to take your range from that point to 17. Since `iNbRow = ilastrow -20` this seems possible. I am not saying for sure this is the answer, but I do think it's worth a double check.  Perform a `debug.print` on `range(Rows(iStart), Rows(iStart - 1 + iNbRow)).Address` to see what the range is before you try to copy.

Comment: You're right. I'll look into it more carefully later today when I get the chance to.

Comment: I used the execution window and set a breakpoint on the line where it normally crashes. The row copied was row 13 and the destination was row 17 only (`iStart` and `iStart - 1 + iNbRow` were both equal to 17).

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur -> did you follow the code through and try to copy it?

Comment: I tried just now. I made a breakpoint right before it would do the copy-paste operations. I did it manually, selecting row 13 and then copy + paste formulas + paste formats and no error. When I then resumed the code it crashed on the first Paste. :|

Comment: I made one last try and it was conclusive this time. For some reason PasteSpecial does not like pasting over an array formula even if it's formatting. I made the code do the paste formulas, then specifically told it to copy format from another row that does not contain array formulas and paste it over the same range and it worked. I don't quite see the logic behind that however. Cell formatting should be independant of cell content unless there is a link I do not see.<

Comment: Oh and I gave you the checkmark because your answer IS right.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur -> that was kind of nasty issue, and didn't sound fun to resolve. Glad you got your answer :)

Comment: Well it wasn't critical. I'm just stubborn. Thanks anyway !